# checkradiobox in javascript can't create

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkboxradio

I'm trying to implement checkradiobox from the jquery UI in my code in javascript  however it keeps returning an error saying it cannot be created. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
var HK_button = document.createElement ('input');
$( "HK_button"  ).checkboxradio({label = "h k 0", icon = false });
```

I've also attempted to label HK_button from the start by creating `var label = document.createElement ('label')` to see if that would fix the error but to no avail.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you think `$( "HK_button"  )` would select …?

Comment: `var $HK_button = $("<input>"); $HK_button.checkboxradio({label = "h k 0", icon = false});` Try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$( "HK_button"  )` will not select anything. This is not how jQuery works. Instead you can create an element like so:

```
var $HK_button = $("<input>");
```

and then deal with the checkboxradio by targeting `$HK_button`.

And finally append it to a parent element by making use of the `.append();`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you select it by using '$( HK_button  )'? just out of curiosity and if not, why so?

Comment: @JunhoChoi `$(element)` is used to select either a tag or a class or an ID. What I am doing is creating a jQuery variable so you can select it only by `$HK_button`. Hope this helps! May I ask you to upvote and mark the answer as accepted, so that future visitors can solve their issue faster? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @N.Ivanov, really sorry, but it still seems to output an error. I've put in `var $HK_button = $("<input>");     $HK_button.checkboxradio({label: "h k 0",icon: false}); ` but it still can't create it...

Comment: 'Error: Can't create checkboxradio on element.nodeName=input and element.type=text'

Comment: @JunhoChoi well as the error suggests, you have `type=text` on your input, you have to create a `type="radio"` input for it to work. Please refer to the [jQuery UI Checkboxradio Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/). And I would suggest you to go over some basic jquery tutorials to get you started. Hope this helps!